# "Score of" loses translation after voting on question

Tags: bug, review, voting, localization, score

In the review queues the score of a question (related to the currently reviewed item) is displayed, e.g. in the [low quality posts queue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/):

> [image: Review queue with Russian text]

Here all looks fine until you make a vote on the question. After that the translation is dropped, and original English text is displayed:

> [image: Review queue with original English text]

In the case above I voted up and then down to show you that the same score is displayed differently. So the same translation (depending on the score value) should be used before and after voting up/down.

Animation below:

> [image]